# How do I filter out students to sections in django?

Tags: django

I am very new at Django and I've been struggling to figure out what to do. I am currently making a Learning Management System Project where in teachers can create a course and under that course there are specific students who are enrolled. The problem is I do not know how to do that.

Basically this is what i want to happen:
Each student has its own section and 1 section has its own courses.

Comment: what else to say. You have to start by learning the framework I guess. https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I have background about basic Crud stuffs but i dont have any idea how to implement groups in django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by defining models as follows:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ...

class Section(models.Model):
    ...
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, ...)

class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, ...)
```

OR

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ...
    section = models.CharField(...)

class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, ...)
```

From there, you will need to build the `views.py` where you will defined what will happen at specific actions.

Hope this helps.